# How to enable scrolling when there are not enough items in android ListView

Tags: android, listview, scroll

When implementing a pull-to-refresh `ListView`, I find that if there are no items or only few items, ListView's scrolling is disabled. So I cannot trigger a "pull" event. How can I overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

ListView-scrolling is dynamical, so basically you can't what you want to do in the way you have planned. It might be easier using a GestureDetector take a look at [this](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/app-builder/use-androids-gesture-detector-to-translate-a-swipe-into-an-event/1577), it might help.

Comment: Yes， it is indeed  scrolling when i touch the ListView and the onTouch callback is called. Just i cannot see any scrolling effect. And the header view cannot hide by using `setScrollY()` or `smoothScrollToPositionFromTop()` or other similar methods. It always show.

Comment: Have you set an OnScrollListener on the ListView? If so, can you see in the LogCat that it gets fired when you are scrolling the "short" list?

Comment: I find a solution. I use the thought to hide the header from [link](https://github.com/erikwt/PullToRefresh-ListView). Simply to put the header in a LinearLayout and set header's marginTop to its negative height value.